# How to transfer / move Bigquery Datasets and DAGs from one GCP Organization to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a technical question about migrating GCP resources (DAGs, Datasets, BigQuery Tables) from one source GCP project into another target GCP project (BOTH PROJECTS LOCATED IN DIFFERENT GCP ORGANIZATIONS).

I meant, I already know that we can migrate / transfer BigQuery Datasets and DAGs between regions and also between projects (in the same projects):

for example:

### To migrate Datasets and DAGs between REGIONS:

1. Create a Cloud Composer Environment (in US region).
2. Create two Cloud Storage buckets; one located in the source region and another in the target region.
3. Create the BigQuery destination dataset (in EU).
4. Define the composer workflow (basically create a dummy task -> export BQ table to the bucket -> import table from the bucket).
5. Upload the DAGs and dependencies to the bucket.
6. Trigger the DAG manually.

### To migrate Datasets and DAGs between PROJECTS:

---

Use bq command line tool to copy a table from one project to another. 
You can have a look at the following sample command:

Source:

projectid: 123456789123
dataset: dataset1
table: table1

Destination:

projectid: 0987654321098
dataset: dataset2
table: table2

Command:
bq cp 123456789123:dataset1.table1 0987654321098:dataset2.table2

Via shell script (shell script + bq tool):

```
export SOURCE_DATASET=$1  # project1:dataset
export DEST_PREFIX=$2  # project2:dataset2.any_prefix_
for f in `bq ls $SOURCE_DATASET |grep TABLE | awk '{print $1}'`
do
 export CP_COMMAND="bq cp $SOURCE_DATASET.$f $DEST_PREFIX$f"
 echo $CP_COMMAND
 echo `$CP_COMMAND`
done
```

---

But, how could I migrate those GCP resources BETWEEN ORGANIZATIONS ? I meant, I have some Datasets and DAGs in a source Organization which I
need to copy / transfer to a target project created in a different GCP organization.

How could I do it ?

Thanks a lot,

Regards,